# IComparer.CompareTo(Object a, Object b)

Tags: c#, compareto, icomparer

I have an Arraylist with 10 or more `Level` object. These objects all have a Level ID.
I try now to write an `IComparer.CompareTo(Level a,Level b)`.
I don't really know how to Implement this. Never worked with `IComparer` and when I read the MSDN Libary I don't get smarter.

I tried this:

```
  public int CompareTo(Level a, Level b)
    {
        if (a.LevelID < b.LevelID)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (a.LevelID == b.LevelID)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
            return 1;
    }
this._alLevel.Sort(CompareTo(Level[0],Level[1])
```

`_alLevel` is my `Arraylist` with my `Level` object.

I am a beginner...

Comment: Are the levels really in a non-generic [`ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or are you actually using a generic [`List<Level>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?  Using the generic will make this more straightforward.

Comment: You need to create an instance of the class that implements `IComparer`, then pass that instance to `Sort`.

Comment: You have to create a class that implements the comparator (your CompareTo code seems right).
Then, you pass an instance of this class to the sort method

Comment: i added these Levels in an arraylist yes. Ok so i need to implement a new Class with the Method CompareTo ? and then i pass an instance to the ArrayListSort Method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend you store your levels in a generic [`List<Level>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  It guarantees type-safety in your code and improves performance by removing the need to do run-time casting of objects into the expected type.

But, if you are determined to use a non-generic [`ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you must create a comparer that implements the non-generic [`IComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface, like so:

```
public class LevelComparer : IComparer<Level>, IComparer
{
    #region IComparer<Level> Members

    public int Compare(Level x, Level y)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return 0;
        if (x == null)
            return 1;
        else if (y == null)
            return -1;
        return x.LevelID.CompareTo(y.LevelID);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IComparer Members

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        return Compare(x as Level, y as Level);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

(Note that my comparer also implements the generic [`IComparer<Level>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface so you could use it with a `List<Level>`.  Also, the null checks are there in case the objects cannot be cast to Levels.  In a purely generic comparer I probably wouldn't bother.)

Next, pass an instance of the comparer to the [sort method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e743hdt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of your arraylist:

```
arrayList.Sort(new LevelComparer());
```

Answer (score 1):

I imagine your _alLevel is a `List<Level>`

Then, you need to implement `IComparer<Level>`, like

```
 public class LevelComparator: IComparer<Level> {
  public int CompareTo(Level a, Level b)
  {
    if (a.LevelID < b.LevelID)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (a.LevelID == b.LevelID)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
        return 1;
  }
}
```

Then, you can instantiate the comparator and pass it to `Sort`:

```
  this._alLevel.Sort(new LevelComparator());
```

Inside, the Sort method will use you CompareTo method to perform the sorting

Comment: or just `return a.LevelID.CompareTo(b.LevelID)`;